# Delphi - Form Pass Parameter to Report Builder

Tags: delphi

How to i pass the parameter value from form to Report Builder?

Or any mistake？

Report builder SQL:

```
SELECT * FROM Member Where MemberID = :MemberID
```

Form code:

```
procedure TfmRbTest.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  ppReport1.Template.FileName = 'Member.rtm'
  ppReport1.Template.LoadFileName;
  ppReport1.Parameters['MemberID'].Value := '000001';
  ppReport1.Print;
end;
```

Comment: How is the field MemberID defined in the database?

Comment: Have you tried ppReport1.add('MemberID', dtString, '000001' ) ?  Replace datatype with whatever '000001' happens to be...

Comment: MemberID - VARCHAR(12),

Comment: Hi, John i tried already but not work for me.

Answer (score 1):

You don't provide enough information to be sure, but here is my guess.

You need to be careful with parameter types. The SQL you generate is

```
SELECT * FROM Member where MemberID = 000001
```

If MemberID is text, you need

```
SELECT * FROM Member where MemberID = '000001'
```

which you would generate with the following code

```
procedure TfmRbTest.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  ppReport1.Template.FileName = 'Member.rtm'
  ppReport1.Template.LoadFileName;
  ppReport1.Parameters['MemberID'].Value := '''000001''';
  ppReport1.Print;
end;
```

Alternatively I think you could leave the code as is and change the query to

```
SELECT * FROM Member where MemberID = ':MemberID'
```

but I am not 100% on that.